# Random opacity animation on list of elements

Tags: jquery, css, animation, opacity

I have looked everywhere and can't find the right way to do this, hopefully someone will be able to help here.

Reference Image:
http://theintegrateur.com/grid.jpg

What I want to do is an animation on the ".clients-overlay" span so that when the page loads a random element's overlay has the opacity of 0 for 4 seconds and then goes back to 0.7. Then the same animation happens to a random element in the list.

```
    <ul id="clients-list" class="group">
        <li>
            <span class="clients-overlay">&nbsp;</span>
            <span><img src="img/logo-client.jpg" alt="Client" title="Client" /></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="clients-overlay">&nbsp;</span>
            <span><img src="img/logo-client.jpg" alt="Client" title="Client" /></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="clients-overlay">&nbsp;</span>
            <span><img src="img/logo-client.jpg" alt="Client" title="Client" /></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="clients-overlay">&nbsp;</span>
            <span><img src="img/logo-client.jpg" alt="Client" title="Client" /></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit to loop the function**

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2mEk/1/)

To loop it, you can just put it in a function and have it call itself, like so

```
function changeOverlay () {
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 4) - 1;
    $('.clients-overlay:eq(' + randomNum + ')').animate({ "opacity" : .4 });
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.clients-overlay:eq(' + randomNum + ')').animate({ "opacity" : .7 });
        changeOverlay();
    }, 4000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    changeOverlay();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It looks like it's working for only one element. Basically, when the first random element has opacity back to 0.7, i want the animation to be applied to another random element in a loop. :)

Comment: I hope that satisfies your needs. Let me know if you want a pure javascript version, there is no need for jQuery if this is the only thing you're using it for

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I was looking for and it works like a charm. Do you accept money contribution? :)

Comment: Haha, that is far from necessary. Here on StackOverflow we aim to help out users for no other gain than the pride of helping them. If you'd like to employ me, feel free to contact me at zachsaucier@gmail.com or check out [my personal site](http://zachsaucier.com/)

Comment: Haha alright, if I need your services I will definitely contact you in the near future. Have yourself a great weekend!